# After enter GRUB, I wont boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot, 17.10

I installed Ubuntu 17.10 for my whole hard disk. After I entered GRUB, my Pc freeze with this message:

```
dev/sda1: clean, 59870/30531584 files, 3039822/122096128 blocks
```

In recovery mode, I try to find the real problem with `dmesg`. But no errors i found.

My pc is a x86_64 Intel. UEFI ASUS.

Comment: What brand/model system? Older BIOS or newer UEFI system? May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/